# session_start(): ¿Que es?

Tags: php

Lo que sucede es que cuando no has iniciado sesión cuando cargas los perfiles de otros se la página carga bien, pero cuando inicias sesión los perfiles ya no cargan y mandan error 500. He habilitado los errores php y leído en muchos foros y ninguno me ha ayudado así que decidí hacer la pregunta.

Antes debo aclarar que cuando habilité el log de los errores php se registraba este error:

```
PHP Notice:  session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/tmp/.priv) failed: Permission denied (13) in /homepages/19/d875527769/htdocs/frix.ga/assets/init.php on line 9
```

Luego cuando vi que el archivo se debe guardar en ANSI format no UTF-8 format y lo hice se registraban estos errores:

```
[02-Jul-2021 17:58:28 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/tmp/.priv) failed: Permission denied (13) in /homepages/19/d875527769/htdocs/frix.ga/assets/init.php on line 9
[02-Jul-2021 17:58:28 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /homepages/19/d875527769/htdocs/frix.ga/assets/init.php:9) in /homepages/19/d875527769/htdocs/frix.ga/assets/init.php on line 9
```

Este es el init.php que viene por defecto:

```
<?php
@ini_set('session.cookie_httponly',1);
@ini_set('session.use_only_cookies',1);
@header("X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN");
if (!version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '>=')) {
    exit("Required PHP_VERSION >= 5.5.0 , Your PHP_VERSION is : " . PHP_VERSION . "\n");
}
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
session_start( );
@ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
require_once('includes/cache.php');
require_once('includes/functions_general.php');
require_once('includes/tabels.php');
require_once('includes/functions_one.php');
require_once('includes/functions_two.php');
require_once('includes/functions_three.php');
```

Si es necesario este es es el php.ini

```
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 2024M
upload_max_filesize = 2024M
output_buffering = Off
max_execution_time = 9000
max_input_vars = 3000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 512M
zlib.output_compression = On
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT;
log_errors = On;
display_errors = On;
error_log = /kunden/homepages/19/d875527769/htdocs/frix.ga/php-errors.log;
```

Y el .user.ini

```
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 2024M
upload_max_filesize = 2024M
output_buffering = Off
max_execution_time = 10000
max_input_vars = 9000
max_input_time = 9000
memory_limit = 600M
zlib.output_compression = On
```

¿Alguna idea de porque ocurre? Lo siento si es algo muy básico, pero soy un novato.

Comment: Al parecer solo es cuestión de permisos

Comment: ¿Existe un valor predeterminado para los archivos? Según lo que se archivos son 644 y carpetas 755.